# Explicit instantiation for a set of types

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

In my code usually I have to write a function that takes a "Path-like" type, that is, something that I can convert to `boost::filesystem::path`, for example

- `QString`
- `std::string`
- `const char *`
- etc...

in A.hpp

```
struct A
{
  template <typename PathLike> 
  void myFunction(PathLike path);
};
```

in A.cpp

```
template <typename PathLike> 
void A::myFunction(PathLike path)
{
   boost::filesystem::Path p = convertToBoostPath(path);
   //do something...
}

//Explicit instantiations needed 
template void A::myFunction(string);  
template void A::myFunction(QString);
template void A::myFunction(char const *);
//....
```

The problem is that if I want to do the same thing in a different function `B`, I need to add the explicit instantiations all over again. Maybe I'm taking a wrong approach.

Comment: Why not just define the function in a header file?  You can use SFINAE to constrain the type if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing a template function that takes any `PathLike` and also does the real work, write a template function that takes any `PathLike`, converts it to `boost::filesystem::Path` as shown, then calls a non-template function (whose definition can be in the .cpp) which will do the real work.

In `A.hpp`:

```
class A
{
public:
  template <typename PathLike> 
  void myFunction(PathLike path);

private:
  void myFunctionImpl(boost::filesystem::Path path);
};


template <typename PathLike> 
void A::myFunction(PathLike path)
{
  myFunctionImpl(convertToBoostPath(path));
}
```

In `A.cpp`:

```
void A::myFunctionImpl(boost::filesystem::Path path)
{
  // do something...
}
```

This has the added benefit that misuse of the interface results in compiler errors, not linker errors.

Answer (score 1):

How about create a class `PathLike` and use it:

```
class PathLike
{
public:
    explicit PathLike(const QString& path) : mPath(convertToBoostPath(path)) {}
    explicit PathLike(const std::string& path) : mPath(convertToBoostPath(path)) {}
    explicit PathLike(const char* path) : mPath(convertToBoostPath(path)) {}
    PathLike(const boost::filesystem::path& path) : mPath(path) {}

    const boost::filesystem::path& get() const { return mPath;}
    operator const boost::filesystem::path&() const { return mPath;}
private:
    boost::filesystem::path mPath;
};
```

(I mark other constructor explicit to promote `filesystem::path`, but up to you to add/remove `explicit`).

And then:

```
struct A
{
    void myFunction(PathLike path)
    {
       boost::filesystem::path p = path;
       //do something...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to explicitly instantiate a function template for a pack of types is to take the address of each function instantiation. E.g.:

```
template<class... Ts>
void instantiate_myFunction() {
    auto f = [](auto&&) { return 1; };
    auto initializer_list = { f(&A::myFunction<Ts>)...  };
    static_cast<void>(initializer_list);
}

int main() {
    instantiate_myFunction<std::string, char const*>();
}
```

Comment: You have to write a different `instantiate_myFunction` for every function template you want to do this for, correct? As far as I know the only thing you can do with a function template is instantiate it (as opposed to class templates, which can be passed as template template parameters), sadly...

Comment: @MaxLanghof That is true, using `Path` class is the right solution, IMO.